# Why doesnt this open the webview

Tags: android, xml, webview, imagebutton, android-sdk-tools

I have an ImageButton on navigation_menu_header.xml

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/signIn"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="61dp"
android:src="@drawable/signin"
android:textAlignment="center"
/>
```

And here is my main_activity class code for the button

```
    public void signIn() {
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_menu_header,null);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class));

        }
    });
}
```

The WebViewActivity works fine since I tried with a button that is on the mainactivity.xml but because I have the ImageButton on another xml, it does not open the webview.

Edit Added mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_menu_header">

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_menu_header, navigationView, false);
        ImageButton img =(ImageButton)headerView.findViewById(R.id.signIn);

Comment: What do you mean by navigationView? @Divyesh

Comment: post your main activity xml.

Comment: Done @DivyeshPatel

Comment: nav_view id is Navigation menu. and you used nav_header_main as header view but you are setting click in  navigation_menu_header.

Comment: wait sorry that was the wrong one, I added the right one now @DivyeshPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageButton img =(ImageButton)headerView.findViewById(R.id.signIn);



img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you so much. Do yo mind me explaining what View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); does?

Comment: NavigationView provides Default Headerview, that you add in XML code. now when you want to access headerview, you can use navigationView.getHeaderView(0) code. it is searching for View(Here View is HeaderView) in NavigationView at 0 Position. After that It gives headerview , and you can use it to find other views inside header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the navigation header view to get the button.
Suppose your navigationView is `navigationView`.

First get the headerLayout.

```
View headerLayout = 
navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
```

and then find the button like this.
`ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton)headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.signIn);`

You can then set the click listener to `myButton`.